# Make my own exceptions Java

Tags: java, exception

I try to make my own exceptions in Java.

I have a parent class like :

```
public class PException extends Exception {
    public PException(String msg) {
         super(msg);
    }
}
```

and two children classes like :

```
public class noGoalException extends PException {
    public noGoalException(){
        super("No Goal");
    }
}
```

I call it like that :

in the main :

```
try {
    Starter s = new Starter("res/init");
} catch (PException e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
```

and in my method :

```
 private void parseGoals() throws PException {
     [...]
     if (i == 0) {
        throw new noGoalException();
     }
}
```

and Starter :

```
public Starter(String fileName) throws GPException {
    [...]
    parseGoals();
}
```

I specify that i=0 for the tests.

The probleme is that my exception in never throws. Is there something wrong ?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Note that `e.getMessage();` will not print anything by itself, try `e.printStackTrace()` .

Comment: You have to use `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` instead of `e.getMessage()`

Comment: @Kayaman yes i=0 for mmy tests

Comment: Your try block **only** has a call to a constructor `new Starter("res/init");` The method you have shown us `parseGoals`. There's something you've missed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Berger also mensions in a comment:
instead of `e.getMessage()` do either:

```
try {
    Starter s = new Starter("res/init");
} catch (PException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

or

```
try {
    Starter s = new Starter("res/init");
} catch (PException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If that still not prints anything please provide more code where your i comes from so we can check why the error is not thrown.

Comment: Oh yes it's my fault I forgot System.out.println()..  But even with e.printStackTrace(), nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

This here is not correct and is the reason why you see nothing when the exception is thrown

```
try {
    Starter s = new Starter("res/init");
} catch (PException e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
```

`e.getMessage()` [returns a String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage--) and that is just getting lost in the stack

Do instead:

```
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
```

in the catch

or just call `e.printStackTrace()`